# (Rock, paper and Scissors)How to ask player play again function by Python

Tags: python

Here is my code. I already finish the win function call gameplay(Rock beats scissors. Scissors beats paper. Paper beats rock) and asking the player to play again function call replay. However, I didn't know how to complete the replay function into the main class.

```
    def gameplay(userinput1,userinput2):
        if userinput1 == 'Rock' and userinput2 == 'Scissors':
            print('Player 1 win')
        elif userinput1 == 'Rock' and userinput2 == 'Paper':
            print('Player 2 win')
        elif userinput1 == 'Rock' and userinput2 == 'Rock':
            print('Tie')
        elif userinput1 == 'Paper' and userinput2 == 'Rock':
            print('Player 1 win')
        elif userinput1 =='Paper' and userinput2 == 'Scissors':
            print('Player 2 win')
        elif userinput1 =='Paper' and userinput2 == 'Paper':
            print('Tie')
        elif userinput1 == 'Scissors' and userinput2 == 'Paper':
            print('Player 1 win')
        elif userinput1 == 'Scissors' and userinput2 == 'Rock':
            print('Player 2 win')
        elif userinput1 =='Scissors' and  userinput2 == 'Scissors':
            print('Tie')

    def replay():
        return input('Do you want to play again? Y or N:').lower().startswith('y')


 userinput1 = str(input('Your are player1, Enter Rock, Scissors or Paper :'))
 userinput2 = str(input('Your are player2,Enter Rock, Scissors or Paper :'))
 gameplay(userinput1,userinput2)
```

Comment: you need a while-loop.

Comment: This question has probably been asked/answered before: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+rock+paper+scissors

Comment: Thx for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your questions is a little unclear but from what I understood, you should make a loop that calls gameplay and replay. (like @Daniel said) Kind of like this:

```py
while True:
  userinput1 = input('Your are player1, Enter Rock, Scissors or Paper :')
  userinput2 = input('Your are player2,Enter Rock, Scissors or Paper :')
  gameplay(userinput1,userinput2)
  if replay() == False:
    break
```

If you have any confusion, ask away!

**Edit:** Thanks @AndressaCabistani. The input function returns a str type, so we don't need to convert a str into a str.

Comment: Just one thing, all inputs are strings, so the str outside input is not necessary!

Comment: @AndressaCabistani Wdym? Where?

Comment: str(input('Your are player1, Enter Rock, Scissors or Paper :'))

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear enough. All inputs are strings, till we decide to change it. Try ```ans = input("Is this a string? ")
print(isinstance(ans, str))```, the output will be a str even if I type an integer 3 as input, it will be a "3". Try it at your computer. So as a hint, the str() is not needed in this code, because "rock" "paper" "scissors" is already string.

Comment: @AndressaCabistani OH! Thx

Comment: Thx!! As @AndressaCabistani said, str is not necessary. I understand that but I came from java so It just my habit!! Thx anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this without a `while` loop, using recursion. Also, simplified the main `game` function:

```
def game(p1, p2):
    win = ('rock','scissors'),('scissors','paper'),('paper','rock')
    p1, p2 = map(lambda x: x.lower().strip(), [p1, p2])
    if p1 == p2:
        return 'tie!'
    elif (p1, p2) in win:
        return f'player 1 wins, {p1} beats {p2}'
    elif (p2, p1) in win:
        return f'player 2 wins, {p2} beats {p1}'
    else:
        return f'invalid choice(s): {p1}, {p2}'

def _again():
    resp = input('play again?')
    return resp.lower().strip()[0] == 'y'

def play():
    p1 = input('player 1:\n')
    p2 = input('player 2:\n')
    print(game(p1, p2))
    if _again():
       play()
```

Comment: Right, you're testing 9 conditions, even though there are only 3 possible outcomes: p1 wins, p2 wins, tie (and possibly a fourth: invalid input(s)). by defining the winning conditions in a tuple (or list, etc.) we can remove that redundancy and make the code a bit easier to read & maintain :)

Comment: Thx for your commend :)